# How to prevent div aligning to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jstree

In this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ak4Ed/139/

When I click a node (which loads the iframe) the tree structure aligns to the bottom of the iframe. How can I align the tree to remain at the top of corresponding iframe ?

I've tried adding `margin:0px;` to the div which contains the tree but it does not work.

Here is the fiddle code :

```
<div id="demo1" style="height:100px;display:inline-block;margin:0px;">
     <ul>
         <li id="node_1_id">
             <a>Root node 1</a>
             <ul>
                 <li id="child_node_1_id">
                     <a>Child node 1</a>
                 </li>
                 <li id="child_node_2_id">
                     <a>Child node 2</a>
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </li>

     </ul>
     <ul>
                    <li><a>Team A's Projects</a>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a>Iteration 1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a>Story A</a></li>
                                <li><a>Story B</a></li>
                                <li><a>Story C</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                        <li><a>Iteration 2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>Story D</a></li>
                              </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
 </div>
 <div style="display: inline-block;">
    <iframe id="preview" src=""></iframe>
</div>

$(function() {

    $('#preview').toggle();
    $("#demo1").jstree({
        "plugins": ["ui", "html_data", "themes", "hotkeys"]
    });

    $("#demo1").on("select_node.jstree", function() {
        var node = $(this).find("a.jstree-clicked").parent("li");

        $('#preview').show();
            $('#preview').attr('src', 'http://www.google.com')

        alert("selected node: "+node.attr("id"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add "vertical-align:top" to div style

```
<div id="demo1" style="height:100px;display:inline-block;margin:0px;vertical-align:top">
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ak4Ed/140/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the tree to stay on top of the iFrame:

```
<div id="demo1" style="height:100px;display:inline-block;margin:0px;margin-right:100%">
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hatefull/ak4Ed/142/)

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/ak4Ed/143/)**

just add this to css

```
 #demo1
{  position:fixed;

    }
```

**or**
append  `position:fixed;` in div with id demo1

```
<div id="demo1" style="position:fixed;height:100px;display:inline-block;margin:0px;vertical-align:top">
```

Hope this helps,Thank you